# AWSとXserverへのリクエストの振り分けのアーキテクチャー

Tags: aws, nginx

■質問
リクエスト時のhoge.com配下のパスによって、AWSのALBかXServerかにリクエストを振り分けるようにしたい。どうやるのがよいか？

■状況
- hoge.comというドメインを所有
- hoge.com配下のパスによって、AWSのALBかXServerかにリクエストを振り分けるようにしたい
- 今はhoge.comがXserverに行くようにDNS設定している

■AWS
ALB
└TG-EC2(サービスA with Rails)
└TG-EC2(サービスB with Rails)
https://hoge.com/servicea/*
https://hoge.com/serviceb/*

■Xserver
Xserver(サービスC with WP)
http://hoge.com
http://hoge.com/about
http://hoge.com/blog

■困っていること
 - Xserverでリバースプロキシが設定できないので、AWS側にリクエストをもってこれない
 - AWSのALBをリクエストの一次請けにしようにも、ALBからXserverにはリクエストを転送できない

■補足
別サービスなら、そもそもサブドメインをきればいいじゃん、という話もあると思います。
それも含めてアドバイスいただけると助かります

Answer (score 1):

ご認識のとおり、ALBのターゲットはEC2になるため、Xserverへリクエストを直接転送することはできません。
XserverへnginxなどでプロキシするEC2を用意すれば可能ですが、だったらXserver使わなければいいのではという感じでメリットが無いと思います。

AWSのサービスとして実現可能な構成としてはCloudFrontを利用する形となります。

- CloudFrontのWebディストリビューションを作成。CNAMEに `hoge.com` を設定
- オリジンを2つ作成

  - ALBを指したもの
  - Xserverを指したもの
- ビヘイビアで、パスに応じて、ALBとXserverに向ける

注意点としては、デフォルトだとCloudFront側のキャッシュが有効になるので、コンテンツの特性に応じてキャッシュを無効にしたり、必要なヘッダを転送するよう設定する必要があります。

> 別サービスなら、そもそもサブドメインをきればいいじゃん、という話もあると思います。

サブドメインを切ればDNSだけで設定できるので悩むことはないですが、すでに稼働しているサービスだと、SEOの観点で、リダイレクト設定などを行う必要がありそうです。
新規であれば、分けてしまうほうが楽だとは思います。